# Doesn't draw my grid properly in objective C

Tags: objective-c, ios, core-data, grid

I have a problem with counting my module. I am doing the following.

```
- (void)makeGrid:withData:(NSDictionary * )data
{
    NSLog(@"aantal is: %d",[data count]);

    int xStart = 0;
    int yStart = 0;
    int xCurrent = xStart;
    int yCurrent = yStart;



    int xStepSize = 165;
    int yStepSize = 251;

    int xCnt =  3  ;
    int yCnt = [data count] % 3;

    int cellCounter = 0;

    UIView * gridContainerView = [[UIView alloc] init];
    [keeperView addSubview:gridContainerView];

    for (int y = 0; y < yCnt; y++) {
        for (int x = 0; x < xCnt; x++) {
            printf("xCurrent %d  yCurrent %d \n", xCurrent, yCurrent);
            NSString *url1 = @"player_imgUrl";
            NSString *url2 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", x];

            NSString *url3 = [url1 stringByAppendingString:url2];
            NSData* imageData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[data objectForKey:url3]]];
            UIImage* myImage = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:imageData];

            UIImageView * myView = [[UIImageView  alloc] initWithImage:myImage];
            CGRect rect = myView.frame;
            rect.origin.x = xCurrent;
            rect.origin.y = yCurrent;
            myView.frame = rect;
            myView.tag = cellCounter;
            [gridContainerView addSubview:myView];

            //just label stuff
            UILabel * myLabel = [[UILabel alloc] init];

            [gridContainerView addSubview:myLabel];
            //--------------------------------

            xCurrent += xStepSize;
            cellCounter++;
        }

        xCurrent = xStart;
        yCurrent += yStepSize;
    }

    CGRect repositionRect = gridContainerView.frame;
    repositionRect.origin.y = 100;
    gridContainerView.frame = repositionRect;

}
```

My NSLog says that in my data object are 16 values. And when I run it, it only shows 3 imageviews. Does anybody know what I am doing wrong?

Please help,

Kind regads.

Answer (score 0):

After reading your code, the number of imageviews should be (xCnt * yCnt).

Your problem is here:

int yCnt = [data count] % 3;

the yCnt is 1 when your data is 16, that's why your result is 3 imageviews only.

to overcome this issue, you should do the following:

```
yCnt = (data.count / xCnt) + 1;

for (int y = 0 ; y < yCnt; y++)
{
    for (int x = 0; x < xCnt; x++)
    {
        if ((y == (yCnt - 1)) && (x > (data.count % xCnt)))
        {
            break;
        }
        else {
            // Your Grid code here
        }
    }
}
```

Hope This helps.

Comment: the code written inside your for loops (i.e. the code used to draw the imageviews)

Answer (score 0):

```
int yCnt = [data count] % 3;
```

gives 1 when [data count] == 16;